# Why do I get "ModuleNotFoundError" when I run my spider?

Tags: python, scrapy, pipeline

I am using **scrapy 1.5.2** with python 3.

I have a very simple spider and I created a small pipeline to transform the date field of my item.

Here is my tree folder of my project "entreprises" : http://prntscr.com/o8axfc

As you can see in this screenshot, I created a folder "pipelines" where I added the `tidyup.py` file where I added this code:

```html
from datetime import datetime

class TidyUp(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        item['startup_date_creation']= map(datetime.isoformat, item['startup_date_creation'])
        return item
```

You can see also in my screenshot I added in `settings.py` of my project the parameters :

```html
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'entreprises.pipelines.tidyup.TidyUp': 100}
```

Here is the code of my spider usine-digitale2.py:

```html
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser


def parse_details(self,response):
    if "item_name" not in response.body:
        open_in_browser(response)
        
    item=response.mega.get('item',None)
    if item:
        return item
    else:
        self.logger.warning("pas d'item reçu pour %s", response.url)
        
        
        

class UsineDigital2Spider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'usine-digital2'
    allowed_domains = ['website.fr']
    start_urls = ['https://www.website.fr/annuaire-start-up/']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths="//*[@rel='next']")),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths="//*[@itemprop='url']"),
             callback='parse_item')
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        i = {}    
        
        i["startup_name"] = response.xpath("//h1/text()").extract()
        i["startup_date_creation"] = response.xpath("//*[@itemprop='foundingDate']/@content").extract()
        i["startup_website"] = response.xpath ("//*[@id='infoPratiq']//a/@href").extract()
        i["startup_email"] = response.xpath ("//*[@itemprop='email']/text()").extract()
        i["startup_address"] = response.xpath ("//*[@id='infoPratiq']//p/text()").extract()
        i["startup_founders"] = response.xpath ("//*[@itemprop='founders']/p/text()").extract()
        i["startup_market"] = response.xpath ("//*[@id='ficheStartUp']/div[1]/article/div[6]/p").extract()
        i["startup_description"] = response.xpath ("//*[@itemprop='description']/p/text()").extract()
        i["startup_short_description"] = response.xpath ("//*[@itemprop='review']/p").extract()
        
        return i
```

When I run the command :

`scrapy crawl usine-digital2 -s CLOSESPIDER_ITEMCOUNT=30`

I get this error message :

> **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'entreprises.pipelines.tidyup'; 'entreprises.pipelines' is not a package**

And here is log in my terminal :

http://prntscr.com/o8azt0

I searched everywhere in my code. I don't see any errors. This code is from the book "Learn Scrapy" (from Dimitrios Kouzis-loukas) where I follow instructions. I don't understand why it doesn't work.

You can find all source code of scrapy project "entreprises" here :

https://github.com/FormationGrowthHacking/scrapy/tree/master/entreprises

As I am reading the book "Learn Scrapy", you can easily guess I am a newbie tring to develop his first scraper. I would appreciate a lot the help of some expert.

Kind regards

Comment: Typo in the module name?

Comment: Try to create an empty file __init__.py in the directory entreprises/ https://stackoverflow.com/q/448271/11451509

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `pipelines` folder **and** `pipelines.py` file in your project, which is causing the issue.

[image]

I recommend removing the folder and move your pipeline class into `pipelines.py` file

**or**

Remove `pipelines.py` and add `pipelines/__init__.py` with this import:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from .tidyup import TidyUp
```

Also in `settings.py`:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'entreprises.pipelines.TidyUp': 100}
```